# Typeahead JS Autocomplete not working - can't find anything

Tags: javascript, php, database, laravel, typehead

I want to make a autocomplete function on my input with existing titles from database, but seems that doesn't work. I don't know what's the problem but when I try to write something, notting happens.

**Here is my controller**

```
   public function search()
    {
        return view('search-me');
    }

    public function autocomplete(Request $request)
    {
          $data = Models::select("email")->where("email", "LIKE","%{$request->input("query")}%")->get();
          return response()->json($data);

    }
```

**Here is my route**

```
 Route::get('search-me', array('as' => 'search', 'uses' => 'AdminNewsController@search'));
 Route::get('autocomplete',array('as' => 'autocomplete', 'uses' => 'AdminNewsController@autocomplete'));
```

**Here is my view**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h1> test</h1>
    <input type="text" class="typeahead form-control">
</div> 


</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var path = "{{ route('autocomplete') }}";
       $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
           source: function (query, process){
           return $.get(path, { query: query}, function (data) {
               return process(data);
           });
           }
       });

</script>
</html>
```

I'm using Laravel 5.2 but I guess is working on mine too. Here is the tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AiMsvobceY

Comment: No errors in the console? Or your DevTools/Network tab? Does your autocomplete route return results?

Comment: Here is an error : when I type any character I get this : `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` and the file with problem is jquery.

Comment: `404` means page not found. Did the route can be accessed correctly? Or did the Http request addressing to correct route?

Comment: Oh so I've changed the route, now is `search-me`, now I have this error : `bootstrap3-typeahead.js:214 Uncaught TypeError: it.toLowerCase is not a function` . I updated my code .

Comment: @DedyChaidir I've changed the link for typeahead, now I have `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.10.6/jquery.typeahead.min.js"></script>`, but no errors in console...

Comment: I've tried with this version (on your question page) > `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"></script>` and having no problems. But when I tried with the second version script in your comment > `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.10.6/jquery.typeahead.min.js"></script>` no http request is made by the autocomplete, no wonder there is no error. I dont know how its going in your machine.

Comment: So with the first link worked fine? Maybe now is other problem? Because I got `bootstrap3-typeahead.js:214 Uncaught TypeError: it.toLowerCase is not a function`...